# Zeppelin UI OOM

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I have a heavy task in zeppelin such that when I run that paragraph multiple times, the Zeppelin /jobs status page will return HTTP 500 error with OOM.

What's some possible causes of this?

I'm running client-mode with spark on yarn.

Answer (score 0):

There might be many reasons for OOM in spark interpreter of Zeppelin. One possible cause is

- Scala REPl inside spark interpreter persists all evaluated values (variables, anonymous functions, and so on) in memory ([SI-4331](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4331))

> ```
> scala> case class A()
> defined class A
>
> scala> new A() 
> res0: A = A()
> scala> new A() 
> res1: A = A()
>
> scala> List(1, 2, 3, 4).map(x => x+1) // anonymous function
> ```

You can increase driver memory by setting `spark.driver.memory` for spark in `$SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-defaults.conf`

- in case of local spark, you can set the same option in the interpreter option page (`localhost:8080/#/interpreter`, [spark interpreter configuration](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/latest/interpreter/spark.html#configuration))
- if you are using crontab in Zeppelin, you can use `auto-restart interpreter on cron execution`.